# Why am I getting a long response time using a combination of string and structured searches with a start and end date?

Tags: marklogic

The MarkLogic Search Developer's Guide discusses using a combination of string queries and structured queries where the requests are ANDed together. I have a string query consisting of 31 terms and a structured query consisting of an indexed starting date field. The search completes in less than 20 seconds. Here is a dump of the parameter map:

```
2021-09-24 22: 49: 13.306 Info: resource.xqy paramMap: {
    "pageLength": 10,
    "q": "(T1 OR \"T2\" OR \"T3\" OR \"e-T4\" OR \"T5\" OR 
    \"T6\" OR \"T7\" OR \"T8\" OR \"T9\" OR \"T10\" OR
    \"T11\" OR \"T12\" OR \"T13\" OR \"T14\" OR \"T15\" OR 
    \"T16\" OR \"T17\" OR \"T18\" OR \"T19\" OR \"T20\" OR 
    \"T21\" OR \"T22\" OR \"T23\" OR \"T24\" OR \"T25\" OR 
    \"T26\" OR \"T27\" OR \"T28\" OR \"T29\" OR \"T30\" OR \"T31\")",
    "format": "json",
    "options": "all",
    "structuredQuery": "{
        \"query\":{
            \"queries\":[
                {
                    \"and-query\":{
                        \"queries\":[
                            {
                                \"and-query\":{
                                    \"queries\":[]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                \"range-query\":{
                                    \"range-operator\":\"GE\",
                                    \"value\":[\"2000-09-10T04:00:00.000Z\"],
                                    \"range-option\":[],
                                    \"json-property\":\"primarydate\",
                                    \"type\":\"xs:dateTime\"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    \"operator-state\":{
                        \"operator-name\":\"results\",
                        \"state-name\":\"highlight\"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }",
    "start": 1
}
```

However, if I add an end date for comparison, the search takes over 5 minutes to complete. Here is the revised parameter map:

```
2021-09-24 22: 57: 44.930 Info: resource.xqy paramMap: {
    "pageLength": 10,
    "q": "(T1 OR \"T2\" OR \"T3\" OR \"e-T4\" OR \"T5\" OR 
            \"T6\" OR \"T7\" OR \"T8\" OR \"T9\" OR \"T10\" OR
            \"T11\" OR \"T12\" OR \"T13\" OR \"T14\" OR \"T15\" OR 
            \"T16\" OR \"T17\" OR \"T18\" OR \"T19\" OR \"T20\" OR 
            \"T21\" OR \"T22\" OR \"T23\" OR \"T24\" OR \"T25\" OR 
            \"T26\" OR \"T27\" OR \"T28\" OR \"T29\" OR \"T30\" OR \"T31\")",
    "format": "json",
    "options": "all",
    "structuredQuery": "{
        \"query\":{
            \"queries\":[
                {
                    \"and-query\":{
                        \"queries\":[
                            {
                                \"and-query\":{
                                    \"queries\":[]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                \"and-query\":
                                {
                                    \"queries\":
                                    [
                                        {
                                            \"range-query\":
                                            {
                                                \"range-operator\":\"GE\",
                                                \"value\":[\"2000-09-10T04:00:00.000Z\"],
                                                \"range-option\":[],
                                                \"json-property\":\"primarydate\",
                                                \"type\":\"xs:dateTime\"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            \"range-query\":{
                                                \"range-operator\":\"LE\",
                                                \"value\":[\"2010-09-10T04:00:00.000Z\"],
                                                \"range-option\":[],
                                                \"json-property\":\"primarydate\",
                                                \"type\":\"xs:dateTime\"
                                            }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    \"operator-state\":{
                        \"operator-name\":\"results\",
                        \"state-name\":\"highlight\"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }",
    "start": 1
}
```

I would expect it to complete faster given the reduced time frame.

What's up with that? The MarkLogic database version is 10.0-5.

Comment: Is is consistently that slow if you re-run the query? How many records are returned?

Comment: Yes, it is consistently slow. The query with the start date returns 432,196 records in about 10 seconds. The query with the start and date returns 408,346 records in over 5 minutes.

It seems to me that the query is not optimal. There are over 14,000,000 documents in the database that have a date less than the end date, while there are around 3,000,000 documents with a date greater than the start date, so I wonder if the query tries to AND the search string query with the structured end-date query before further reducing the results by the structured start-date query. How can I debug that?

Comment: check xdmp:plan() or xdmp:query-meters

Comment: In order to use xdmp:plan() or xdmp:query-meters(), and to try to recreate the error in an xquery call, I think I need to construct the query using search:search as long as I can combine the string query with the structured query. I'm looking for examples.

It's either that or I use the /v1/search or /v1/values API and try to instrument the request with the plan or query-meters.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to try. First, isolate it to qconsole. I'm not sure exactly what interface (Java API?) you are getting the log from, but it can be converted to a simple query condition like (hand edited):

```
let queryCondition = cts.andQuery([
  cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery("primarydate", ">=", xs.dateTime("2000-09-10T04:00:00.000Z"), 
  cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery("primarydate", "<=", xs.dateTime("2010-09-10T04:00:00.000Z"), 
  cts.wordQuery("T1", "T2", "T3")
])
```

or similar.

Test just the index resolution portion (not the doc retrieval) of this via `cts.estimate(querycondition)` or `cts.uris(null, null, queryCondition)`

If this reproduces the error you can tune the query from there.

My guess is that your system is overloaded. This is not a very big query, and your DB is also not large, so these times are way too high. You may be out of memory, swapping, or have other system issues maybe with disks.

But either way, I would first get it into qconsole, and isolate exactly what query is running, just for index resolution, and which part is causing the issue by removing query bits until you find the minimal combination that runs slow.

Also note that you can return `xdmp.queryMeters()` or `cts.plan(queryCondition)` at the end of the qconsole buffer and that will work. No need for search.search() conversion for either.

Comment: cts.estimate is not reproducing the error.

Comment: We have some custom code to handle what should otherwise be  simple RestAPI calls. The requests is parsed and processed via a call to submitted to the /MarkLogic/rest-api/models/search-model-query.xqy model. The results are then compressed using xdmp:zip-create() before returning to the user. I think there might be a problem with this middleware, hence why I wanted to try to use search:search to recreate the combined string and structured query without using search-model-query.xqy .

Meanwhile I'm trying to do the due-diligence of evaluating resource limitations and optimizing the query.

Comment: So when I asked the original developer of the code how to debug this, they said to simply copy the query from the access log into the query console and to enable profiling. However, the query comes in as a Rest API call. I don't know that it makes sense to try to profile the RestAPI call. In addition, I don't know how to run a rest api call in the query console without invoking xdmp:http-post or xdmp:http-put to do that. It seems to me that the HTTP request will be profiled and not the Rest API call. Comments, suggestions?

I think need to test search-model-query.xqy - where is that?

Comment: Hi Madds,

I have yet to implement the xquery plan in the invocation sequence. I'm trying to figure out how to add it to the UI and Node.js calls. However, I made an interesting discovery.

In the above code where I set the upper bound of the date range where it times out with a value of "2010-09-10T04:00:00.000Z", 

cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery("primarydate", "<=", xs.dateTime("2010-09-10T04:00:00.000Z"),

if I change it to the current date, e.g., "2021-11-16T04:00:00.000Z", then it completes without the long delay. This makes absolutely no sense to me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Good news. If xdmp.estimate(thequery) runs fast, the range index change is probably not relevant (all the index work takes place when you estimate the query.

Sounds like middleware or something outside MarkLogic.